# How to do the same operation until it reaches one condition

Tags: php

How to do the same operation until it reaches one condition?
For Example:

```
<?php
  $n = rand(5,157);
  if ($n=='63'){
    echo 'ok';
  } else {
    //* another random, until rand () will give 63  *//
  }
?>
```

how can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm curious to know the context where you need a such pattern. It's very strange.

Comment: `do { $n = rand(5, 157); } while ($n != 63);`.

Comment: Luc M: I have to check if an auto-generated number is already on the database, so I asked for a code that is easy to then get inspiration :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [while loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php):

```
<?php
  $n = rand(5,157);
  while ($n != 63) {
    $n = rand(5,157); // n is not 63, get another number
  }

  echo 'ok';
?>
```

`if` will check for condition once, whereas `while` will check condition until it is not `true`

Answer (score 1):

Look at PHP [while loops](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php).  We want to keep generating a random number **while** the last does not equal 63.  So use:

```
$n = rand(5,157);

while($n != 63){
    $n = rand(5,157);
}

echo "ok";
```

So `$n` is set to an initial value and each while loop generates a new value of `$n` then checks it.  When `n=63` the loop breaks and the "ok" is echoed.